# Count how many values fall in each bin

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, partition

Suppose that I have a set partitions `P` over the interval `[0,1)`. `P` has the length `N`. For example:

```
P = np.array([0,0.05,0.1,0.3,0.7,1])
```

which divides `[0,1)` to the following intervals:

```
[0,0.05), [0.05,0.1), [0.1,0.3), [0.3,0.7) , [0.7,1)
```

I have another array `U` of length `K` over `[0,1)` whose elements are `u+i/K` for `i = 0,...,K-1` where `0<u<1/K`. For example

```
U = np.array([0.03,0.13,0.23,0.33,0.43,0.53,0.63,0.73,0.83,0.93])
```

I want to count the number of elements in `U` that fall into each partition `j = 0, ..., N-1`. In this example, we have

```
C = np.array([1,0,2,4,3])
```

Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

One way is using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to obtain the indices where the elements in `U` should be inserted in `P` to maintain order, followed by [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to get a count of the number of occurrences of each index:

```
np.bincount(np.searchsorted(P,U))[1:]
# array([1, 0, 2, 4, 3])
```

Or with [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) assuming the bins always increase monotonically:

```
np.bincount(np.digitize(U,P))[1:]
# array([1, 0, 2, 4, 3])
```

---

**Details**

```
P = np.array([0,0.05,0.1,0.3,0.7,1])
U = np.array([0.03,0.13,0.23,0.33,0.43,0.53,0.63,0.73,0.83,0.93])
```

As mentioned, `np.searchsorted` will return the indices at which the elements in `U` should be inserted in `P` so that the latter remains ordered:

```
s = np.searchsorted(P,U)
# array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5])
```

The next thing we want is to count the number of occurrences of each index. For this we can use `np.bincount`, which will do exactly what we want. Note that the returned binning array will have up to `np.amax(x)+1` counts, meaning that it will also output a count of `0` for missing values, `2` in this case, which corresponds to the interval `[0.05,0.1)`:

```
np.bincount(s)[1:]
# array([1, 0, 2, 4, 3])
```